# How to use dwplot to plot model.average for glmm?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is an example of waht I want:

[image]

This is terrible because when I checked the summary of my averaged model   as below(I use conditional average part), I found that the significant terms have issues,such like water , shouldn't have been significant but really significant in the below plot, I don't know how to resolve it . 
And  do we use the dwplot to plot them? I think the dwplot is a good method all the time.

```
Model-averaged coefficients:  
(full average) 
                      Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)    
cond((Int))           1.920090   0.162094    0.162496  11.816   <2e-16 ***
cond(semi_habitats)   0.186583   0.097901    0.098116   1.902   0.0572 .  
cond(SHDI)           -0.129630   0.151271    0.151428   0.856   0.3920    
cond(tree)           -0.162590   0.124409    0.124601   1.305   0.1919    
zi((Int))             1.500601   0.128244    0.128614  11.668   <2e-16 ***
cond(water)          -0.044410   0.081564    0.081655   0.544   0.5865    
cond(YEAR2019)        0.085849   0.197617    0.197803   0.434   0.6643    
cond(other_crop)      0.043594   0.099623    0.099674   0.437   0.6618    
cond(maize)           0.052875   0.096160    0.096256   0.549   0.5828    
cond(cotton)          0.014107   0.060640    0.060688   0.232   0.8162    
cond(wheat)          -0.031901   0.095976    0.096014   0.332   0.7397    
cond(pesticide_June) -0.008873   0.051123    0.051208   0.173   0.8624    
cond(buildings)      -0.001023   0.015340    0.015378   0.066   0.9470    

(conditional average) 
                     Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)    
cond((Int))           1.92009    0.16209     0.16250  11.816   <2e-16 ***
cond(semi_habitats)   0.19525    0.09131     0.09156   2.133   0.0330 *  
cond(SHDI)           -0.24078    0.12546     0.12581   1.914   0.0556 .  
cond(tree)           -0.20019    0.10737     0.10765   1.860   0.0629 .  
zi((Int))             1.50060    0.12824     0.12861  11.668   <2e-16 ***
cond(water)          -0.13278    0.09032     0.09056   1.466   0.1426    
cond(YEAR2019)        0.37262    0.25029     0.25093   1.485   0.1376    
cond(other_crop)      0.17128    0.13086     0.13101   1.307   0.1911    
cond(maize)           0.15044    0.10785     0.10809   1.392   0.1640    
cond(cotton)          0.12061    0.13636     0.13654   0.883   0.3771    
cond(wheat)          -0.27238    0.11467     0.11494   2.370   0.0178 *  
cond(pesticide_June) -0.12006    0.14837     0.14877   0.807   0.4197    
cond(buildings)      -0.03181    0.07962     0.07985   0.398   0.6904
```

What I used the technology is glmmTMB and I have been proceeding the model averaging with dredge & model.avg with `MuMIn`packages and directly save it to `rds`file.

```
LCWJuneLS1avg.rds = readRDS("LCWJuneLS1avg.rds")
mA <-(LCWJuneLS1avg.rds) #pulling out model averages   #

df1<-as.data.frame(mA$coefmat.subset) #selecting full model coefficient averages

CI <- as.data.frame(confint(LCWJuneLS1avg.rds, full=T)) # get confidence intervals for full model
df1$CI.min <-CI$`2.5 %` #pulling out CIs and putting into same df as coefficient estimates
df1$CI.max <-CI$`97.5 %`# order of coeffients same in both, so no mixups; but should check anyway
setDT(df1, keep.rownames = "coefficient") #put rownames into column
names(df1) <- gsub(" ", "", names(df1)) # remove spaces from column headers
ggplot(data=df1[-1,], aes(x=coefficient, y=Estimate))+ #again, excluding intercept because estimates so much larger
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "red",linetype="dashed", lwd=1.5)+ #add dashed line at zero
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Estimate-AdjustedSE, ymax=Estimate+AdjustedSE), colour="blue", #adj SE
                width=0, lwd=1.5) +
  coord_flip()+ # flipping x and y axes
  geom_point(size=8)+theme_classic(base_size = 20)+ ylab("Coefficient")
```

Here is my dataset: 
file.name :   LCWJuneLS1avg.rds
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C3vzpA17Ewfu5ZXWp-BNLE0_VEgkeq6b